# there is some problems in my code

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($databasehost,$dbname,$dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_query($con,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$query = file_get_contents("php://input");
$sth = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (mysql_errno()) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $query.'\n';
    echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)){
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

What's the problem?

This is the error:

```
[19-Jan-2018 09:17:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource on line 22
```

Comment: mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$dbname","$password") you mixed mysql in mysqli

Comment: You cannot mix [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions. Besides that, **the `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql_*()` PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). They are old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4265352) to learn more about why and how.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`.

The latter is deprecated as of version 5.5.0.

Try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)`

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php also.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is you are mixing mysqli and mysql.

Try to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)`.

And, in `mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database")`, you are missing the user name.

```
// (1) make sure $username is defined.
$con = mysqli_connect($databasehost,$username,$dbname,$dbpassword) or die(mysqli_error());

// check to use mysqli_, not mysql_
mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_query($con,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$query = file_get_contents("php://input");
$sth = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (mysql_errno()) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $query.'\n';
    echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
    $rows = array();

    // (2) Use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_assoc.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

        // (3) $r is not defined. Use $row.
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

Comment: i change mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth) to mysql_fetch_assoc($sth).

after that
i have this error: PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: Have a look to [documentation](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) : `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); if ($result) { $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); }` will solve your problem. Maybe you have a problem in your `$query`.

Comment: can you give me the solved code?

Comment: i have this error:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'gamebuster_payamak'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You have to check your credentials : `$databasehost, $username, $dbname, $dbpassword`.

Comment: that problem solved..but now i have this error:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result